# Next 2 hours using Calendar object/Java-Android

Tags: java, android, calendar

I want to capture the number of steps the user is doing for the next 2 hours.

This is what I am putting.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Log.d("Calendar",calendar.getTime().toString());
long endTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,2);
long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

However the app is crashing giving me the following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid end time: 1432119600355
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Please show the *complete* exception - we currently don't know what call is failing.

Comment: Maybe the exception is that your start time should be before your end time, which now is not so

Comment: Thanks for the replies my friends. It is fixed:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at what you're doing:

```
long endTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,2);
long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

So your *start* time is two hours after your *end* time. That's not going to be valid. I suspect you just need to change the ordering:

```
long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,2);
long endTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

That will now have a start time of midnight and an end time of 2am. (Although you haven't cleared the millisecond part, so it'll be "some time in the first second after midnight" etc.)